# Allow user interaction in views behind a fullScreenCover in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, interaction

I have a view that shows an animation briefly that needs to be in front of everything (including on top of any presented sheets which means a `ZStack` or `.overlay` will not work).  `.fullScreenCover` works, however, it blocks any interaction with the content underneath and I'd really like to not block interaction.  I have tried `.allowsHitTesting(false)` and `.presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)` but neither of those seem to work with `.fullScreenCover`.  Does anyone know of a way to do this purely in SwiftUI?  I think there might be some ways with a scene delegate and going through UIKit, but I'd really rather not do that...

Comment: It is only possible with `sheet`

Comment: Doesn't even work with a `.sheet` and that also scales down the underlying view.  At least I can make the `.fullScreenCover` clear and it doesn't affect the underlying view (I just can't interact with the underlying view).

Comment: Why not add it overtop of the window itself?

Comment: @valosip that does work!  I had to add the `overlay` to the topmost view in the `WindowGroup` when I was trying to insert the view lower in the hierarchy and bypass like `fullScreenCover` does but for my needs, having it at the top does work and I can use the `.allowsHitTesting(false)` to prevent interaction and allow taps through the view.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create an `.overlay` on the top-most view in the `WindowGroup` and in the view in the `.overlay` use `.allowsHitTesting(false)` to disable interaction and pass taps through to underlying views.